# Fuzzy Search and Plurals

Tags: search

So I’ve got fuzzy search activated and it works as it should... going to the right; but if I have a plural? Is there no way around this?

Search term: "intaglio" = 12 results … includes "intaglio" and "intaglios”

Search term: "intaglios" = 9 results … only includes “intaglios”

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem... are you expecting "intaglios" to match "intaglio"?

Comment: Yes, if someone searches intaglios, intaglio does not show up.

Comment: I might be asking the impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the current search implementation in Craft, if you have `subLeft` and `subRight` set to `true` for the [defaultSearchTermOptions](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching#supported-syntaxes) config setting and you search for "intaglios", what Craft does behind the scenes is [search for](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching#supported-syntaxes) `*intaglios*`, which would never match `intaglio` because the wildcard is after the last `s`.