# Search forms handling of plurals

Tags: search

Is it possible to include plural variations? For example if I search for 'apple' but the entry includes 'apples' it appears.

Or would this need to be approached by getting these variations into the entries via tags or similar?

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score').section('newsEvents') %}


{% if entries|length %}
<h3>{{ entries|length }} result(s):</h3>

    {% for entry in entries %}
         ...
    {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
     <p>Your search for "{{ query }}" didn't return any results.</p>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly achieve a very rudimentary form of plural search by following the recommendations in [AbbeyDesign's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/20389/505).

However, it comes with an important caveat: **it won't work for plurals which do not include the singular form**.

For example, baby / babies, knife / knives, or tooth / teeth.

If you need to accommodate this requirement, Craft's built-in search probably isn't going to cut it, and you'll need to go with something a bit more sophisticated.

I haven't personally tried it, but I think [Search Plus](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus) can handle this. It's basically a convenient wrapper around [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com), a very sophisticated search tool, which automatically handles pluralisation.

Comment: Ok thank you. I've added subRight. If I needed to handle doing it the other way around (searching 'apples' and returning 'apple') is there a more manual way of doing it such as adding tags to cover these variations? I assume if they don't output these tags on the front-end they wouldn't appear in results, I'd have to do a display:none.

Comment: You could, in theory, create a "keywords" field, in which you explicitly list the singular and plural form of each desired search term, and tell Craft to search against that field (as described in [the documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching)). However, this would require an enormous amount of patience, discipline, and indeed foresight on the part of the content author, and wouldn't scale at all.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to enable fuzzy search as explained here in Craft Docs:

[Enable Fuzzy Search](https://craftcms.com/support/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default)

But there's a little caveat you'll run into when you search for "apples" and expect to return "apple"

[Fuzzy Search and Plurals](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15933/fuzzy-search-and-plurals)

Comment: Important note: setting the `subRight` config to `true` will ensure that "apple" also matches "apples". Setting the `subLeft` config to `true` will result in "apple" also matching "grapple", which probably isn't what you want.