# Product Search - redactor description field not indexing

Tags: search, config

I am struggling to get my head around plurals and fuzzy search etc.

I have seen this article, which seems to help answer this but am hoping someone can clarify based on my scenario
[Search forms handling of plurals](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/search-forms-handling-of-plurals/20389#20389)

If i search commerce products for 'sponge' i seem to get results that the word's 'sponge' and also 'sponges' which is great.

If I search for 'sponges' I get the 'sponges' results but ALSO I thought I would get the singular 'sponge' results, but this does not seem to be the case. This is what I want to achieve - is this possible?

In config I have:

```
    'defaultSearchTermOptions' => array( 
        'subLeft' => true,
        'subRight' => true,
    ),
```

//////////////////////////////////

Can anyone clarify what results i should expect or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks
Malcolm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the expected behaviour](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15939/141). To say that the native search in Craft has support for plurals, is a stretch. What the search options indicate is whether or not to allow for extra characters to the left and right in the indexed keywords, when searching for a term.

So, if "sponges" is indexed, "sponges", "sponge", "spon", or "pong", would result in a match when using `'subLeft' => true` and `'subRight' => true`. If they were false, only "sponges" would match.

If the indexed word is "sponge" and you search for "sponges", there will be no matches because "sponges" is not a subset of "sponge".

If you want more advanced search capabilities, you need to integrate some kind of third-party search engine like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with André's answer, Craft does support [fuzzy search](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/enabling-fuzzy-search), which is what you have setup.

If you are looking for better search capabilities, agreed that [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/relevance-overview/) would be the best suit, you can use the [Scout plugin](https://github.com/studioespresso/craft-scout) to support pushing content to your index. It is getting support for PHP 8 very shortly too. You can then use this in multiple ways, not only to just show results, you can easily incorporate autocomplete or for more out-the-box filtering you can incorporate Algolia's [InstantSearch.js](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/what-is-instantsearch/js/)